# Expected value theorem

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

If for any arbitrary function $\phi(\cdot)$
$$E(\phi(X))=E(\phi(Y)),$$
then $X=Y$ a.s.

Can somebody name this theorem?

Comment: Doesn't have a name because it's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $E[\phi(X)]=E[\phi(Y)]$ for every $\phi$, the most you can conclude is that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution. This follows from taking $\phi(x) = I(x\in B)$ as $B$ ranges over an appropriately large collection of sets.

To see why $X=Y$ need not be true, even if $X$ and $Y$ are defined on the same space, consider $X$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and take $Y:=1-X$.